# how to overload assignment operator in c++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I have the following struct:

```
struct mystruct{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}
```

I simply want to overload "=" to make `mystruct A = mystruct B`
equal to:

```
A.a = B.a;
A.b = B.b;
A.c = B.c;
```

(fields assignment respectively)

How I should make it?

Comment: Please clarify what programming language you're using.

Comment: @RaymondChen I'm using cpp

Comment: The default assignment operator works as what you want.  i.e. You don't need to overload `=` operator.  And what's your problem? you don't know how to do operator overloading? Have you checked any intro books of C++?

Answer (score 0):

```
struct mystruct{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    mystruct& operator=(const mystruct& other)
    {
        a = other.a;
        b = other.b;
        c = other.c;
        return *this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The automatically generated assignment operator works already as that. But assuming, this was only an example and you want to do something else, please consider:

```
struct mystruct {
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
  mystruct& operator=(const mystruct& other) {
    this->a = other.a;
    this->b = other.b;
    this->c = other.c;
    return *this;
  }
};
```